# How can I add shells to the list in Run Shell Script in the Automator now that the .plist is on the read-only volume?

Tags: terminal, automator, script, plist

This question has what seems like a duplicate [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146462/how-can-i-add-shells-to-the-list-in-run-shell-script-in-the-automator), but I have an update.

The answer to that question -- how to add a shell to Automator -- is to modify Shells.plist.  Specifically:

> The list of these shells in this action come from this PLIST file -->
> "/System/Library/Automator/Run Shell
> Script.action/Contents/Resources/Shells.plist"

But it looks like Apple has moved `Shells.plist` to the read-only drive which has been new since Catalina.

[image: xCode error message]

It seems like *way* too much of a hack to log into recovery mode to edit this one `.plist` file.  Is there another way to add a shell (specifically the Fish shell) to Shells.plist?  Can I put that `.plist` file somewhere else, so that it gets picked up in addition to the existing one?  Or is there another way to add a shell to Automator?

The mystery deepens: I went to re-create the action from scratch and `fish` was present in the dropdown.

[image: fish lives!]

That didn't work, and when I went back to edit the script that I'd just created, `fish` was gone!

[image: Can you see the fish?]

Comment: Also, the answer to this question I suppose is also the answer to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435021/add-fish-to-automator?noredirect=1#comment624778_435021

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/local/bin/fish` is in `/etc/shells`? I have a homebrew-installed `bash` in `/opt/homebrew/bin` and it shows up in the Run Shell Script dropdown menu as expected.

Comment: Ah, but only if a pull a new shell script action out of the library. As soon as I select another shell, the entry disappears. Strange.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/fish` is indeed in `/etc/shells`.

Comment: And if you pull a new shell action from the library into the right side of the automator window, which shell is selected by default?

Comment: `zsh` is the shell selected by default.

Comment: I believe it selects by default whatever the user's default shell is.  My shell is /usr/local/bin/ksh, and that's what Automator chooses by default.  Yes, that shell is in /etc/shells.